# How do i make collection images bigger on my website. i use shopify ecommerce

Tags: html, css, shopify

How do I make collection images bigger on my website? I use Shopify eCommerce. Individual images are good. they appear big and resolution is decent as well. however in category pages images are a bit smaller.
I'm not really good at HTML. but I'm trying to figure it out for days now.

Comment: would you share your code about exactly what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use element inspector in browser to find images and their classes on collection page. And when you will find out the needed classes, you can update css styles for it to make images bigger. If you provide us with a link to your store, I will give you more precise guideline.